# Count number of LIKE-matches per Entry

Tags: mysql, string, match

I try to explain what I mean by matches on a simple example:

I have a table `myprods` like this:

```
id | name
1    galaxy s4 mini
2    samsung galaxy s4
3    galaxy galaxy s3
4    iphone 4s
5    apple iphone 4s
```

I'd have this query so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM   myprods
WHERE  name LIKE "%samsung%" OR name LIKE "%galaxy%" OR name LIKE "%s4%"
```

The result of my query is:

```
id | name
1    galaxy s4 mini
2    galaxy s4
3    galaxy galaxy s3
```

and now I'd not only return the matched rows but also the number of hits. ONE hit would be if ONE of the LIKE-phrases applies to the row. So in this case I would expect the hits to be 0, 1, 2 or 3. That means: the LIKE phrase `"%galaxy%"` should NOT be counted as two hits for the id=3, it just counts as "hit" or "not hit".

The expected result would now be:

```
id | name               | hits
1    galaxy s4 mini       2
2    samsung galaxy s4    3
3    galaxy galaxy s3     1
```

Possible in a performant mysql phrase?
Or should I rather select only the rows with my query above and then match the single substrings to the returned names via `strpos` in PHP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In MySQL, boolean expressions can be used as integers -- with 0 for false and 1 for true.  So, the following works:

```
SELECT p.*,
       ((name LIKE '%samsung%') + (name LIKE '%galaxy%') + (name LIKE '%s4%')) as hits
FROM   myprods p
WHERE  name LIKE '%samsung%' OR name LIKE '%galaxy%' OR name LIKE '%s4%';
```

EDIT:

If MySQL, you can also express this query as:

```
SELECT p.*,
       ((name LIKE '%samsung%') + (name LIKE '%galaxy%') + (name LIKE '%s4%')) as hits
FROM   myprods p
HAVING hits > 0;
```

The use of `having` in this context is a SQL extension and doesn't work in other databases.  But, it does allow a query to refer to a column alias for filtering, without using a subquery.

Comment: oh well, that looks nice. To have it returned as an integer wont affect the performance in comparison to a SQL statement with only the LIKE-phrases within the Where clause, would it?

Comment: @tim . . . Doing `like` 6 times instead of 3 times shouldn't have a bit impact on performance.  However, there is an alternative as the edited answer offers.

Comment: I thought that maybe mysql would internally organise it so that it doesn't actually become 6 times because of the duplicate LIKE-phrases ;-) but yeah, your edit is very nice, thanks for that :-)

Comment: One more thing what came to my mind: Is it possible to count the number of characters which match as a sum? That means, a hit with `samsung` and `galaxy` would be *worth* 7+6=13 (still 2 hits), and 2 hits with `samsung` and `s4` would be worth 7+2=9, so a longer hit would count **more**

Comment: I just came up with something like: `((name LIKE '%samsung%')*7 + (name LIKE '%galaxy%')*6 + (name LIKE '%s4%'))*2 as hitlength` as addition to the query. Useful? :-)

Comment: Tried and working... :-) Doubles the number of like-matches but hopefully, mysql will sort that out internally :)