# Get most matched result on top in mysql LIKE query

Tags: mysql, sql-like, word-boundaries

Say I have a table like this:

Table: `businesses`

```
+----+------------------------+
| id | name                   |
+----+------------------------+
| 1  | Carolyn Wong Cakes     |
| 2  | Cupcakin Cackes Shop   |
| 3  | Wong Cackes Shop       |
| 4  | Indie Cakes & Pastries |
+----+------------------------+
```

I want to get the `best matched result` while I search for some words inside name.
for example I want to search: `Wong Cackes Shop` which is 3 words.
I use this query for above search:

```
SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE ( 
  name LIKE '% Wong %' OR 
  name LIKE '% Cackes %' OR
  name LIKE '% Shop %'
)
```

I expect `record 3` to be the first matched result but the result is:

1. `Carolyn Wong Cakes` // with `2` matching words
2. `Cupcaking Cackes Shop` // with `2` matching words
3. `Wong Cackes Shop` // with `3` matching words

How can I search words and get records with most matched result on top of other results ?

Like this:

1. `Wong Cackes Shop` // with `3` matching words
2. `Cupcaking Cackes Shop`
3. `Carolyn Wong Cakes`

EDIT: My `word-boundaries` LIKE method also has a problem. it won't get results which start or end with one of 3 words. because of those `spaces` in `LIKE '% word %'`
for example:
`Wong[space]` // does not match
`[space]Wong[space]` match
`[space]Wong` // does not match

Thanks.

Comment: question resembles other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153515/mysql-count-number-of-like-matches-per-entry

Comment: Have you looked at FULLTEXT indexes?

Comment: @Strawberry my table engine is `innoDB`. does it support FULLTEXT ?

Comment: You're confusing me with google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following should do the trick

```
SELECT 
  name,
  (( name LIKE '%Wong%')+( name LIKE '%Cackes%') +(name LIKE '%Shop%')) as total
FROM businesses WHERE ( 
  name LIKE '%Wong%' OR 
  name LIKE '%Cackes%' OR
  name LIKE '%Shop%'
)
ORDER BY total DESC
```

You can even delete the where clause here, since you're just interested in the total number of hits.
In order to overcome the problem of the spaces, just eliminate them in the like-clauses. `%wong%` will match `[space]wong` OR `[space]wong[space]` or `wong[space]`

Comment: could you please look the edited post. there is a problem with `spaces` in like query.

Comment: @Bee157, After eliminate the space, it creates problems like "Workshop". These words means differently, and will include into top pages of the search result.

Comment: @Michael regexp should do the trick to eliminate problems with "Workshop"

Answer (score 0):

It's doing correctly since it will search for the word only. In your case, you should search for the entire string `Wong Cackes Shop` (OR) best would be implementing [`FULL TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/current/en/fulltext-search.html) search